# typeahed showing only first character of all suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, autosuggest, bootstrap-tags-input

I am new to typeahead.js.

I am making taginput + typahead:

I did it well but i am stuck on issue where only first character of suggestion is showing up.

```
$('#name_t1').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {                  
    source: function(query) {
      return $.get('<?php echo base_url('search/search_player') ?>');
    }
  }
});
```

Code works fine but I don't know why only single characters are poping out.
please help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE68x.png)

includes:

```
<script src="<?php echo VENDOR."custom/bootstrap-typeahead.js"; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo VENDOR."custom/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"; ?>"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 input-group pull-left">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">Players:</span>
                            <input type="text" id="name_t1" value="" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12 m-t-xs">
                        <hr>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" placeholder="Unpaid" tabindex="7" class="form-control error"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" placeholder="Paid" tabindex="8" class="form-control green"></div>
                        </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function search_player()
    {
        //header("Content-type: application/json");
        $term = $this->input->post('query');
        $query  = $this->player_model->get_player($term);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query as $key => $value) 
        {
            $data[] = array('name' => $value->name);
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Model:

```
function get_player($term)
    {

        $query = 
            $this->db->select('id')
             ->select('name')
             ->from('player_list')
             ->like('name', $term)
             ->get();
        return $query->result();
        //$query = $this->db->get('player_list');
        //return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: please update `HTML` code in the question. Current code is not enough

Comment: What does your AJAX get request return in response? Does it return full strings?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: If I call my controller directly from browser url bar (like : localhost/jits/search/search_player), then I am getting json object:

`[{"name":"Prince"},{"name":"Dako"},{"name":"Jito"},{"name":"Gogi"},{"name":"Rajo-p"},{"name":"Savan"},{"name":"Tapan"},{"name":"Kaka"}]`... this is output of `json_encode($data);`.